# Vulnerability: path traversal in. The solution provided by sonar does not work

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

When I use Sonar, it tells me that the vulnerability exists: path traversal in. Sonar indicates how to solve it but even though I follow its indication, it keeps detecting the vulnerability, does anyone know how to make it sound? Although it is a case of false positive since the route is internal I want it to disappear in sonar.

[image]

Comment: I suggest just closing that issue as false-positive or wont-do

Comment: Assuming that `rutaConfig` isn't provided as a user input the statement "in many cases the constructed file path cannot be controlled by the user" applies so it is a false positive.